# Windows 10 Azure AD join

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am trying to join a Windows 10 PC to Azure AD in the out-of-box experience. Could you please tell me what build of Windows 10 should i use for the same. Because i am not getting the proper set-up steps.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the latest preview from here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/preview-iso

Once you have Windows 10 installed, go to Settings App, System, About and choose the option "Connect to Cloud" Use your Azure Credentials to add.  Once done, it is worth restarting your machine.

Then check in your Azure AD to see if the Computer has joined.

Also don't forget to create your unique PIN

And here is a  a great article that will take you through the entire setup:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/05/28/azure-ad-join-on-windows-10-devices.aspx